# Is there a way to put a dataframe as the value of a specific column in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data that has column names and values to create a dataframe.

However one of the column values is another dataframe is it possible to do this in pandas, or are each column values meant to be a single value?

For example what I am trying to achieve would look something like this;

```
df
out:
   A  B  C
0  A1 B1 D  E
         D1 E1
         F  G
         F1 G1
```

This is where letters that have numbers with them are the values, and just letters are the column names.

Comment: that is called `MultiIndex` in pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Comment: @Wen Will have a look now, thanks for pointing out, I tried to scour the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Add the initial dataframes

Comment: @Bharathshetty do you mean to the  column value?

Comment: I think your formatting might be off. Also, are A1, etc dataframes? Does df have only one row? It is possible to put one dataframe in the cell of another dataframe, but it's probably better to use multilevel indexing. For putting one dataframe in the column of another dataframe, it's less clear what you mean.

Comment: @Acccumulation Sorry for poor explanation. I tried to say that the letters with numbers are normal values, and just letters are column names. Does this make sense? But as you and Wen have mentioned multilevel indexing looks like what I need, going to have a read through and see what I can do.

Comment: Yes column values or the dataframe you currently have

Comment: If A and B contain single numbers, and C contains a dataframe, then another option would be to do a dictionary: data_dict = {A:A1, B:B1, C:sub_dataframe}

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to put another dataframe (or any type of object) in a pandas cell.

```
In[2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(2)})
       df1

Out[2]:    
            a
        0   0
        1   1

In[3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(3), 'y':range(3)})
       df2

Out[3]: 
            x   y
       0    0   0
       1    1   1
       2    2   2


In[4]: df1['b'] = [df2, {'cat':'meow', 'otter':'clap'}]
       df1

Out[4]:
            a   b
       0    0   x y 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
       1    1   {u'otter': u'clap', u'cat': u'meow'}

In[5]: df1.get_value(0, 'b')

Out[5]:     
            x   y
       0    0   0
       1    1   1
       2    2   2
```

As you see it's not very readable to print a dataframe contaning another dataframe. If you want it to look as your example you should go with multiindex as Wen suggested.